# hover a code every 1 second

Tags: jquery, css

I have a sprite image with three images init, I would like to change image position every second while the mouse is hovering the image

what i've tried:

```
  $(".miniPosterImg").hover(function () {
      setInterval(function () {
          thismarginLeft = $(this).css("margin-left").replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
          if (thismarginLeft < 360) {
              thismarginLeft = thismarginLeft - 120;
              //}else{
              //      thismarginLeft = 0;
          }
          $(this).css("margin-left", thismarginLeft + "px");
      }, 1000);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/377Ja/4/

Comment: And what's wrong with it?

Comment: You do realize that if you want to change the position on hover, they will no longer be hovered over it, right?

Comment: What happened?? result?  did you missed to callback(clearInterval)??

Comment: Use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` on hover in and out respectively.

Comment: @JoshC OP is using a sprite. The background image is being shuffled around but the containing element will not be moving.

Comment: @gvee - it *will* move... `$(this).css("margin-left", thismarginLeft + "px");` ;)

Comment: @Archer correct. I should have been more specific: with sprites the overflow *should* be hidden by the parent. Therefore whilst the sprite itself might move, only the visible portion can be hovered over. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're code is repeating continuously.  So add **`clearInterval`** in your **callback**.

But careful, you need to use variable like below

```
var toggle;
$(".miniPosterImg").hover(function() {
    toggle = setInterval(function(){
        thismarginLeft = $(this).css("margin-left").replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
        if(thismarginLeft < 360){
                thismarginLeft = thismarginLeft-120;
        //}else{
        //      thismarginLeft = 0;
        }
        $(this).css("margin-left", thismarginLeft + "px");
    },1000);}, 
    function(){
          clearInterval(toggle);
    }
});
```

**Updates from your comments:**

Better have a separate method to handle **`setInterval`** like this

```
tToggle = function () {
    thismarginLeft = $('.miniPoster').css("marginLeft").replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
     if(thismarginLeft < 360){
            thismarginLeft = thismarginLeft-120;        
    }
    $('.miniPoster').css("marginLeft", thismarginLeft + "px");
}
```

Then use like this

```
var toggle;
$(".miniPosterImg").hover(function () {
    toggle = setInterval(tToggle, 1000);
},
function () {
    clearInterval(toggle);
});
```

Also **FYI:**

```
$('.miniPoster').css("margin-left")  //WRONG
$('.miniPoster').css("marginLeft")  //CORRECT
```

[**Working JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/377Ja/11/)

Comment: You need to define `var toggle` outside the function. Otherwise the variable will be undefined in the callback: http://jsfiddle.net/377Ja/3/

Comment: @user1671639 I'm receiving `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined ` in chrome console

Comment: @PatsyIssa I couldn't get you.

Comment: @user2783132 Can you make a fiddle?  it seems the problem is other part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) on hover and then, on mouse out, you should clear de interval with [`clearInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp).

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/377Ja/

```
var myInterval

$(".miniPosterImg").hover(function() {
    myInterval= setInterval(function(){
        thismarginLeft = $(this).css("margin-left").replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
        if(thismarginLeft < 360){
                thismarginLeft = thismarginLeft-120;
        //}else{
        //      thismarginLeft = 0;
        }
        $(this).css("margin-left", thismarginLeft + "px");
    },1000);
}, function(){
    clearInterval(myInterval) ;
});
```

Comment: The problem is in your code. Not in the solution I gave. You can not use `margin-left`. The console throws an error... You should use `marginLeft`.

Comment: like this? `        $(this).css("marginLeft", thismarginLeft + "px");`

Comment: @user2783132 now you are asking for a solution to another problem. Please open a new question for that. I supplied an answer for the question you did and the clear and set of the interval i provided works as expected.

Comment: @user2783132 not in CSS, but you are dealing with jQuery. You can find examples of `marginRight` in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a sprite, I believe the attribute you want to change is background position

Try this:

```
.miniPosterImg:hover{
    /*only doing animation for chrome, use other prefixes to replicate in other browser*/
    -webkit-animation: slideImage 1s;
    background:url(/*your url*/);
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideImage{
   0%{background-position: 0px 0px}
   50%{background-position: -120px 0px}
   100%{background-position: -240px 0px}       
}
```